# Integrate with a map under an UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have an `UITableView` inside an `UIScrollView` and I want that the user will be able to scroll just when he touches the `tableView` (I have a map in the background and I want that the user will be able to integrate with the map when the `tableView` doesn't covers all of it but the `scrollView` blocks the touch (the scrollView is all over the screen), can anyone help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you set the map view as the tableHeaderView of your table view rather than using a scroll view?

Comment: I want the tableView to cover the map when the user scrolls, not the map to cover the tableView, do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes but you can do that by setting the tableheaderview adding the map view as a subview then adjusting its frame in scrollview didScroll.

Comment: but also the map wouldn't cover the tableView if it were the tableHeaderView it would scroll with table. But, if you wanted to have the effect of covering the map you would say set the origin.y of the map view equal to scrollView.contentOffset.y